# How to have ordered list keep the numbers left-aligned rather than right-aligned?

Tags: html, css

How do I make an ordered list work like this, where the numbers are left-aligned (so it doesn't mess with my layout)?

```
1. hello
2. x
...
9. x
10. I am left aligned.
...
99. x
100. I am left aligned.
```

Rather than this (right aligned, the default):

```
    1. hello
    2. x
    ...
    9. x
   10. I am right aligned.
   ...
   99. x
  100. I am right aligned.
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: That is a strange requirement. It will make the list harder to read

Comment: It won't make it hard to read, as the indentation only occurs after 10, then after 90, then after 900 some items. It is rare, but if you have a list of 10,000 items, it makes sense to format it this way.

Comment: Perhaps use a grid instead and have a CSS counter using ::before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a lot of complicated answers where the solution is pretty easy:

```css
ol {
 list-style-position: inside; /* this is what you need*/
 
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) might be a good choice, with [support](https://caniuse.com/css-counters) goes all the way back to IE 8:

```js
/* Just to generate all the elements we need */

const ol = document.querySelector('ol');

for (let i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  if (Math.log10(i) % 1) {
    li.textContent = 'x';
  } else {
    li.textContent = 'Left-aligned.'
  }
  ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: list;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  counter-increment: list;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(list) '. ';
}

/* Demo only */
ol {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
</ol>
```